# Website spark training

Tags: msdn, websitespark

Just joined the website spark program, which is a great deal in my opinion.

But i still have one question, at the program details page (http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/Support.aspx?tab=ProgramDetails) the following is mentioned as a benefit:
'Free online training Managed newsgroups on MSDN (a community of over six million developers) and other Microsoft online properties'.

I have never been a member of MSDN so I don't know if this training is part of that? But I can't find anything on msdn subscription and training either (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa718661.aspx)

Does anyone have a clue what they mean?

Comment: I think Microsoft is giving their server and SQL server for free with support for development on Microsoft platform for small organisations. Its business strategy don't think anything related to programming

Comment: There seem to be a few training videos on the websitespark page, they probably mean that. I was hoping on some free certification e-course or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [msdev: WebsiteSpark Training Courses](http://www.msdev.com/Directory/SearchResults.aspx?productId=34#0,1)?